# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) after adding spread view to my project

Tags: iphone, class

i added spread view classes to  my project

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MDSpreadView", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in ScheduleManagement.o//schedulemanagement is my file name where iam using the spread view
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MDSpreadViewCell", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in ScheduleManagement.o
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

(null): error: unable to open executable '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eCloudBiz-cwrayrablmglmodqkocxscmbrooo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/eCloudBiz.app/eCloudBiz'

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you forgot to check the "Add to Target" box when importing the MDSpreadViewCell class.

Go into your Project Settings, make sure your target is selected, click the "Build Phases" tab, and add "MDSpreadViewCell.m" to the "Compile Sources" pane.